# ionic 1 integrate specific google analytics in specific screens

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, event-tracking, ionic-v1

I would like to know how to integrate `ionic v1` with `google analytics`
and to track specific screens.

For example, I want to have google analytics code UA-XXX and to track specific navigation (tab1, tab2, etc)

Answer (score 1):

This question is **too vast** so I am not going to cover each and every detail but here is how you can integrate Google Analytics to your ionic v1 app's Screens/Tabs.

For this two things are important, first is [life cycle events of Ionic Views](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionView/) and second is Google Analytics's [cordova-plugin-google-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-google-analytics).

For each Tab there should be one controller and in that controller add the Ion View's life cycle events as per your **tracking** requirement. Below are the available events:

FIRST TIME VIEW INITIALIZATION

```
View 1 – loaded
View 1 – beforeEnter
View 1 – enter
View 1 – afterEnter
```

TRANSITION FROM ONE VIEW TO ANOTHER

```
View 2 – loaded
View 2 – beforeEnter
View 1 – beforeLeave
View 2 – enter
View 1 – leave
View 2 – afterEnter
View 1 – afterLeave
```

But I think you may meed only below two events mainly, `enter` and `leave`:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
  // Your Google Analytic event code of your choice
  window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY', 30);
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(){
  // Your Google Analytic event code of your choice
  window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY', 30);
});
```

**References:**

- Check this link for detailed information about usage of Google
  Analytic APIs:
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-google-analytics#javascript-usage
- Nice working example of Ionic View life cycle events:
  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKBgVg
- Simple article to explain ionic views life cycle events:
  https://www.gajotres.net/understanding-ionic-view-lifecycle/

Comment: tqvm, i'll have a look this weekend

Comment: I cant get it to work, can you please check the code and output: https://dpaste.de/FT1P. tqvm. It has this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startTrackerWithId' of undefined

Comment: @Axil please read the documentation carefully. There is no `$cordovaGoogleAnalytics`. Why did you add this and why are you calling like this `$cordovaGoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-79154745-1');`. Check the documentation again and  call like this `window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA--79154745-1', 30);`

Comment: i tried doing window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA--79154745-1', 30); and it was same problem - Cannot read property 'startTrackerWithId' of undefined. Have you tried this before ? Also I'ved only tried with browser, not on device

Comment: Are you fulfilling the **Prerequisites**?

Comment: Im not clear of the Prerequites https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-google-analytics#javascript-usage this says that Google Analytics SDK is to be installed. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-analytics/ which is the same looks pretty straightforward. 
How do I check the plugin version since there is release notes for v1.0.0, v1.7.x, v1.7.11 but from config.xml/package-lock.json it shows 0.1.14